# How to push down activity content while loading ad in android?

Tags: android, xml

I want to push content while loading ad at the top of the activity, just below the action bar. For this, I used `alignParentTop = "true"` & `layout_height = "wrap_content"` for the `adview`. But in vain.

What is the actual way to push down content while loading ad? If there is no ad, then the content will cover the whole screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add adview in separate layout.
and set visiblility of this layout to GONE if there is no ad.
and when ad load change the layout visibility to VISIBLE.

Comment: I have set visibility GONE in adview, then included the ad layout in activity layout. Also added these in java class: mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });  But no change :(. Ad is loadind at the top but covering some content.

Comment: No add adview in new layout like framlayout. The framelayout.setvisible(visible.gone)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick sample code:

Suppose your content that you want move down is in a `RelativeLayoyet`

You can then make somehting like this:

```
RelativeLayouet rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
if (adIsVisible) {

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  LL = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                LL.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                rel.setLayoutParams(LL);

}else{

                LL.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                rel.setLayoutParams(LL);

}
```

You can change the placement of by changing the `addRule()` values like

```
LL.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
```

You can also make your View (ie. buttons, imageviews, textviews) invisible like this: `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`